# How to decrease the height of mat select dropdown angular 14

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, mat

How to decrease the height of mat select dropdown angular 14

[image]

I have code below

```
<mat-form-field
  class="example-full-width"
  appearance="outline"
>
  <mat-label>Select Project Type</mat-label>
  <!--  [(value)]="selectedCountryId" -->
  <mat-select
    formControlName="projectTypeID"
    required
    (selectionChange)="onProjectTypeChange($event)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let projectType of projectTypeData"
      [value]="projectType.projectTypeId"
    >{{ projectType.projectTypeName }}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error
    *ngIf="addForm.controls.projectTypeID.errors?.required"
  >
    Select one Project Type at least to proceed.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

tried giving height by using style tag and class on mat field tab, but it still does not work

Comment: Even this simple example can help if someone can make this drop down smaller in height


`<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Select Year</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option>2021</mat-option>
      <mat-option>2022</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>`